# Talend TAC import ZIP

Tags: talend

I have a few jobs that I have imported into Talend TAC using the import zip feature. After clicking 'save', I noticed that the job name, version, and context are all surrounded by parentheses. When I try to run these jobs, they appear to immediately become stuck.

I have done this many times in the past and haven't encountered this issue before. These jobs succeed in my local environment and when the jobs are run in TAC they don't produce any exceptions in the error log.

Talend TAC issue:
[image: Talend TAC issue]

Comment: Please include the code you have so far

Comment: Have you updated anything in your environment? How do you export the jobs to create the zips?

Answer (score 0):

Please try after change the browser. Sometimes browser properties also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

1. Stop TAC.
2. Clear the work and temp directories within TAC, usually located as shown below though use the path appropriate for your environment:
   `C:/Talend/6.4.1/tac/apache-tomcat/work`
   `C:/Talend/6.4.1/tac/apache-tomcat/temp`
3. Rebuild the TAC cache. It will take some time to rebuild all of the temporary files, however this should resolve the issue.